# Node.js session-file-store will abort all following requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I'm creating simple web app in node.js which should be able to save session data into file store.

For this purpose I'm using **express-session** with **session-file-store** module:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);

app.use(session({
    store: new FileStore({
        path:'./sessions/',
    }),
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
```

But when I visit some page of my website, I will successfully receive generated HTML file, but all other request for assets will be aborted:

[image: Aborted requests except first one]

When I comment store attribute, it works fine.. but it won't save session data into files.

Does anybody know, what's wrong here? Or do you know any other module for storing session data into files?

Thanks for any advice..

Comment: A minimal test case works without problems here, so I guess the problem is somewhere else. One explanation might be that the folder is not writable. I suggest you to also create a minimal test case where the file session works fine, and then add step by sep all your other routings until it breaks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I have tried:
- configured static content before session middleware (alias don't use session for static content files because of some disk quota restrictions)
- then I specified full address of session folder with __dirname
- and the last thing: I have deleted session folder and restarted application..
But to be honest, I don't know, why it didn't work.
Once again, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have problems with permissions on your file system if it works with default in memory storage.

---

Try to create session store this way:

```
new FileStore({
   path:  require('path').join(require('os').tmpdir(), 'sessions')
})
```

It has to resolve this issue.

Comment: it is possible to make session remain forever. please tell me

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution!