# static file loading on node but on nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am having strange problem in node js .
When I start the dev server by typing

```
node ./bin/www
```

The views are also loaded properly and static file  too  but when I do

```
nodemon ./bin/www
```

Then only views are loaded  for the static file I get this error in chrome console

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Has anyone faced this problem . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually this bug was occured due to this package

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-file-store
```

If you are using this package then on express app then don't follow the default example given

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919667/node-js-session-file-store-will-abort-all-following-requests